# socket.io [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]

Tags: socket.io

My code is:

```
var arrClients = {};
var client = {
        socket:null,
        username:null,
        uid:false,
        time:null
};
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    var sendParmas = {};
    if(isFirstTime){
      client.socket = socket;
      client.username = msg;
      client.uid = uuid.v4();
      client.time = getTime();
      arrClients["'" + client.uid + "'"] = client;
      sendParmas.text=arrClients;
      sendParmas.type='firstTime';
      socket.emit('system',sendParmas);
      socket.broadcast.emit('system',sendParmas);
    }
  });
});
```

client.socket = null; can running ,if not tip: [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]

Comment: Is this your client code or server code? It's a little hard to tell because you have an array of clients but you are also doing the socket.io event listeners like they are client side.

Comment: the code is obviously server side. the event listeners work like that on both server and client side.